# Span of a nonlinear function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Fix vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and a smooth function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define $\phi^d: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ as applying $\phi$ entrywise (i.e. $\phi^d(x_1, x_2, \dots) = (\phi(x_1),\phi(x_2), \dots)$). Under what conditions do we have the equality

$$\mathbb{R}^d=\text{span}(\{\phi^d(\alpha x+y)~\big |~\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\})$$

Clearly if $\phi$ is the identity operator $\phi(x)=x$ or if any two entries of $x$ are equal, this equality does not hold. Main claim is equality holds for generic (i.e. almost all) $x,\phi$ choices.

Comment: Suppose the span is not the full $\mathbb{R}^d$, then there exists a normal vector to the span which we can call $\nu$. This means that $\sum \nu_i \phi(\alpha x_i) = 0$ for all $\alpha$. Take $k$ derivatives with respect to $\alpha$ you still get 0. Evaluate at $\alpha = 0$ you get that $\phi^{(k)}(0) \sum \nu_i (x_i)^k = 0$. So provided not too many derivatives of $\phi$ vanish at zero (generically true), such $\nu$ cannot exist for generic $x_i$.

Comment: For the final claim, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: There could be some typo around, because the question does not make any sense, as it is.

Comment: @Pietro Majer I think that $\phi (x)=(\phi (x_1),\ldots, \phi (x_d)) $.

Comment: So maybe it is a map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: @PietroMajer It's an induced map that the original question also labeled $\phi$ by abuse of notation; I've edited to remove the abuse of notation.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is very clean thanks to Vandermonde connection. Would a similar approach work for
$\text{span}(\phi^d(\alpha x+y)~\big |~\alpha \in \mathbb{R})$ where $y$ is a fixed vector?